# Listbox Trouble with Binding to ItemSource using a ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, listbox

I am having trouble binding to the ItemsSource of a List box control. I would like to be able to add text lines to the List box when the user preforms certain actions.

The SystemControls.xmal Code:

```
<ListBox Grid.Column="4"  Grid.Row="1" Grid.RowSpan="9" ItemsSource="{Binding ListBoxInput}" Height="165" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="listBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="250" ></ListBox>
```

The SystemControls.xmal.cs code snippet:

```
public partial class SystemControls : UserControl, ISystemControls
{
    IDriver _Driver;
    ISystemControls_VM _VM;
    public SystemControls(IDriver InDriver, ISystemControls_VM InVM)
    {
        _VM = InVM;
        _Driver = InDriver;
        DataContext = new SystemControls_VM(_Driver);
        InitializeComponent();
    }
```

The SystemControls_VM.cs This should be where the heart of the problem is. I have gotten it to work in the constructor, when i try to add lines later in the code, for example when a user press a button, it does nothing:

```
public class SystemControls_VM:ViewModelBase, ISystemControls_VM
{
    IDriver _Driver;
    public ObservableCollection<string> _ListBoxInput = new ObservableCollection<string>();


    public SystemControls_VM(IDriver InDriver)
    {
        _Driver = InDriver;

        ListBoxInput.Add("test");//Works here
    }

    public ObservableCollection<string> ListBoxInput
    {
        get 
        { 
            return _ListBoxInput; 
        }
        set
        {
            _ListBoxInput = value;
            //OnPropertyChanged("ListBoxInput");
        }
    }




    public void OnButtonClickGetNextError()
    {
        ListBoxInput.Add("NextErrorClicked");//Does not work here                
    }

    public void OnButtonClickClear()
    {
        ListBoxInput.Clear();//Or Here
    }
```

Also in case it's needed the OnPropertyChangedEventHandler:

```
namespace XXX.BaseClasses.BaseViewModels
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Provides common functionality for ViewModel classes
    /// </summary>
    public abstract class ViewModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged = delegate{};

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    }    
}
```

Comment: Have you checked that the OnButtonClickGetNextError method is actually called? Try putting a breakpoint in it.

Comment: Yup, tried that first. It gets called and the _ListBoxInput shows that it has the additional items in it, but the Listbox itself is never updated with the new items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So got the answer from another source, but figured I would post it here for referance.

So what was happening was that I was setting the data context to one instance of SystemControls_VM while my _VM referance which was handling the button click was going to another instance of SystemControls_VM. That was also why it looked like the button click was working and the List was being populated but no data was getting to the Control itself

I changed the following section of code and it works:

```
public partial class SystemControls : UserControl, ISystemControls
{
    IDriver _Driver;
    SystemControls_VM _VM;
        public SystemControls(IDriver InDriver, SystemControls_VM InVM)
        {
            _VM = InVM;
            _Driver = InDriver;
            DataContext = InVM;//new SystemControls_VM(_Driver);
            InitializeComponent();
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

1) <strike>Your public property is called **_ListBoxInput** but you're binding to **ListBoxInput** (no underscore)</strike>. Make _ListBoxInput private.

2) Because the collection is already observable, you don't need the OnPropertyChanged for your listbox to update.

3) It looks like something might be off with the way you're managing your public vs private ListBoxInput collections. You're calling .Add on your public property (which will immediately raise an event on the observable collection) but then you'll end up adding it to the private collection as well, and then you're calling PropertyChanged on the public property. It's confusing: try my code below and see how it works. (Note in your constructor you add to _ListBoxInput but in your button click event you add to ListBoxInput.)

4) Try adding this.DataContext = this in your constructor

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window {

    public ObservableCollection<string> ListBoxInput { get; private set; }

    public MainWindow() {
       InitializeComponent();
       this.ListBoxInput = new ObservableCollection<string>();
       this.DataContext = this;
    }

    private void AddListBoxEntry_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
       this.ListBoxInput.Add("Hello " + DateTime.Now.ToString());
    }
}
```

and in the xaml, take a look at the [binding Mode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindingmode.aspx).

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding ListBoxInput, Mode=OneWay}"
             Height="165" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
             Name="listBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="250"  />

    <Button Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Name="AddListBoxEntry" 
             Margin="0,0,0,158" Click="AddListBoxEntry_Click" >
             <TextBlock>Add</TextBlock>
   </Button>
</Grid>
```

5) On a separate note, here's another way you could do your INotifyPropertyChanged (I find this cleaner)

```
public abstract class ViewModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged = delegate{};

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
          PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Comment: Added Mode=OneWay to the Listbox ItemsSource. The problem still occurs

Comment: Changes instance of _ListBoxInput to ListBoxInput. The problem still occurs

Comment: Try setting the datacontext. If that doesn't work, start with my sample code in a new project, confirm that it works, and go from there.

Comment: Won't work the datacontext is set to SystemControls_VM already. The problem I am having is most likely with the messages and notifications to this Context (I assume that I am not handling one that I should, just don't know what it is.). I have already gotten this to work just internal to the SystemControls.xaml.cs file but what i need is to get it to work in the referenced DataContext

Comment: I have updated the original question to make it more clear where each piece of code was taken from.

Comment: Also Updated the INotifyPropertyChanged section to your example. That is a bit cleaner. Thanks. However, The problem still occurs.

Comment: I updated my answer - check how you're dealing with _ListBoxInput vs ListBoxInput.

Comment: Ah, sorry. I only updated a piece of my question code with what i changed. Should be better now. I'm calling ListBoxInput in all cases. I tried to Add this.DataContext = this into the SystemControls_VM but said it couldn't find it, which makes sense sence it doesn't inherit UserControl.

Comment: Ah, got an answer from another source, posting now.